# Insert Tuple into SQL using Python

Tags: python

I have created the Tuple as below. I want to insert the follwoing into the SQL database (using import pyodbc).

```
tmpData=[('PRP', 'PRP-000005', 'In Progress', 'UYR', 'uYT'), ('PRP', 'PRP-000006', 'In Progress', 'UYR', 'uYT'), ('PRP', 'PRP-000007', 'In Progress', 'UYR', None), ('PRP', 'PRP-000008', 'In Progress', 'UYR', 'TCP'), ('PRP', 'PRP-000009', 'In Progress', 'UYR', 'OTH'), ('PRP', 'PRP-000010', 'In Progress', 'UYR', None),]

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=Python;'
                          'Database=Test;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "insert into [TBListformstables] values???????
cursor.execute(sql)
```

I am facing a problem in writing this to SQL. What would come at values so that Tuple can be passed

Answer (score 1):

See [executemany](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemanysql-params-with-fast_executemanyfalse-the-default)

> Executes the same SQL statement for each set of parameters, returning
>   None. The single params parameter must be a sequence of sequences, or
>   a generator of sequences.

```
params = [ ('A', 1), ('B', 2) ]
cursor.executemany("insert into t(name, id) values (?, ?)", params)
```

So in your example, something like

```
sql = "insert into [TBListformstables] values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
cursor.executemany(sql, tmpData)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This is what I was looking for.

Comment: I have one variable like Companyname and want to insert in each row. how can I pass one variable name in above ? ... values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,'Google'). it is working, but I want the company name as a variable to pass into SQL.I do not want to insert company name in each Tuple.

Comment: "I do not want to insert company name in each Tuple" -- Why not? It's easy: `tmpData=[tup+(Companyname,) for tup in tmpData]`

Comment: Thanks. I want to insert some 5+ other variables like ( Dept, Auth, Class etc). so this might be cumbersome?? I can add this 5 times. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't see what's cumbersome about `tmpData=[tup+(Companyname, Dept, Auth, Class, Foo, Bar) for tup in tmpData]`. Just make sure you have the same number of `?` in `sql` as the number of items in your tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a JSON object from your list and pass it to the insert query.
Check below:

```
sql = insert into table values(json.dumps(tmpData))
```